# Select Rows That Does Not Contain any Negative Or Missing Value

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Assume a database table has a few hundred columns. In SQL statements, how would you select rows/records that do not contain any negative or missing value? Can you do it using the sqldf package for R users?

Here is an example of data frame with 6 rows and 2 columns:

```
D = data.frame(X = c(23, -24, 35, 12, 34, 41), 
               Y = c(100, 98, 89, NA, 56, 90))
```

The SQL statement(s) should only return a table containing the rows 1, 3, 5, and 6.

Comment: `sqldf::sqldf('select * from D where X>=0 and Y>=0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "X Y
23  100
-24 98
35  89
12  NA
34  56
41  90"
df = read.table(text=text, header = T)
# install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)

conditions = c(">=0","NOT NULL")

columns = colnames(df)

applyConditions <- function(columns,conditions){
  grid = expand.grid(columns,conditions)
  apply(grid, 1, 
   function(x) paste(x, collapse = " ")
  )
  
}
select <- "SELECT * FROM df where "
where <- paste(applyConditions(columns,conditions),collapse = " AND ")

sqldf(paste(select,where))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is master piece! Thank you Mr. Camacho!

Comment: This could be written `where <- paste(outer(names(df), c(">=0","NOT NULL"), paste), collapse = " AND "); fn$sqldf("select * from df where $where")`

Comment: Great add! Thank you GG.